# How to find the marginal distribution of this particular question?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

the question in the link below is to find the marginal distribution of random variables $X$ and $Y$ please refer the questions for details, they says lump the two kinds of failure back together, thereby getting that $X$, the number of successes is a binomial random variable. what is this lump thing? whereas i think it should be according to me $$f(x)=\sum\limits_y\dfrac{n!}{x!y!(n-x-y)!} p^x_1p^y_2 (1-p_1-p_2)^{n-x-y}$$ for all $x\in\ X$, which is surely not correct because the source has different answer. So please do check the link and describe why the marginal distribution of $X$ is $$f(x)=\dfrac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} p^x_1 (1-p_1)^{n-x}$$

[Question link](http://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/106)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what lumping things together is, but, multiplying and dividing by $(n-x)!$,

\begin{align*}
f &=  \sum_y \frac{n! (n-x)!}{x! (n-x)! y!  (n-x-y)!} p_1^x p_2^y (1-p_1-p_2)^{n-x-y} \\
&= \binom{n}{x} p_1^x \sum_y \binom{n-x}{y} p_2^y (1- p_1 - p_2)^{(n-x) - y}\\
&= \binom{n}{x} p_1^x (1-p_1 -p _2 + p_2) ^{n-x}
\end{align*}

where the last equality comes from the binomial theorem.

By symmetry, $y$ is binmially distributed with parameters $n, p_2$. That the two are dependent is then simple.

Comment: Thanks i get the point, any suggestions for better understanding the bivariate distribution.